# Check if a string is in a link list with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to know if there is one word from a list in a string inside one or more text links.

I tried this:

```
keywords = ["word1", "word1", "word1", "word2", "word3"]

html_template = "word4 word2 word1 <a href='#'>the link one<a/> <a \
href='#'>the word1 is link 2<a/> word7 <a \
href='#'>word3 example<a/> word453"

soup=BeautifulSoup(html_template, 'html5lib')
links=soup.findAll('a')

for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in links:
        status="ok"
        break
```

Expected results: If one keyword from keywords is found inside a link from html_template, then status is ok

Comment: can you clarify what you exactly want and add actual/expected results?

Comment: Expected results: If one keyword from keywords is found inside one link from r, then status is ok

Comment: please provide the current `output` of this code. (in order to be a clarified stackoverflow question)

Comment: link = href (link)

Comment: @alexzander it doesn't work at all right now. If I just look at "r" and not at the href link, then it's working. But I want to look at the the link (href)

Comment: you mean you want to see if a `keyword` is located only inside the href, you mean inside here `<a href='#'>the link one<a/>` ?

Comment: inside the text link. WORD1 is not inside this : <a href='#'>the link one<a/>. WORD2 IS inside this : <a href='#'>the link WORD2<a/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to clean your links to get only text without whole tag:

```
links=soup.findAll('a')
clean_links = [link.text for link in links if link.text]
# -> ['the link one the word1 is link 2 word7 word3 example word453', ..]
```

When you use `keyword in <list>`, it checks if there is a list element which is exactly that keyword. But in your case, there are some extra words too. So, you need to check whether that keyword exists in list elements while looping through it, rather than list itself:

```
# defining status to prevent NameError in case keyword is not found
status = None
for keyword in keywords:
    for link in clean_links:
        if keyword in link:
            status = "ok"
            break
# status -> "ok"
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you